# Curve modifier causing twisting instead of straight deformation

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I have a simple rectangular prism that I need to deform nicely along a few curves. I've successfully done so along two, which have no issues. (One is mirrored.) This third one looks like a twizzler and nothing that I've done has fixed it.[image] The other two are arrays that are fitted along curves, and originally so was this third one, but I changed it to just be one shape that fits along the curve in hopes that it might work, and it didn't.

The empty in the middle of the scene is from when I tried to change the array in the hopes that adding an object offset might curb the twisting. It didn't, the rotation was just multiplied by the existing rotation. I also changed the axes and rotated the base object, which made some cool swirls but didn't solve anything.

As far as I know, curves can't twist, since splines don't even have rotation, and since both using an array + curve modifier and just a curve modifier by itself didn't work, I don't know what the issue could be. Any advice would be helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As far as I know, curves can't twist

Curves most certainly can twist, away from their base 0° *Tilt*, which is calculated according to the 'Twist Method' in their Data tab > Shape Panel .

[image]

The *Tilt* of control points can be set in the N panel of the 3D view as shown, or via the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

Below, see the settings for Twist Method for your curve, and the interpolation between control-points, per spline:

[image]